# Send file to server android

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, soa

I've already developed my android app that logs the GPS position and time of the user every 10 minutes and saves it to a .txt file.
Now I need to send this file to a server. I'm now doing it with FTP but that doesn't seem correct as I plan on expanding this to about 10.000 users or more so the FTP approach doesn't seem good.
What other way can I use to send the files to a server? I need this to be relatively secure.
Thanks for your time

Edit: All the answers look very good to me but as far as I know, the only solution that provides secure connection and allows only clients why the password is FTPs.
Is it possible to make web requests and accept only clients with the correct password?

Comment: You are probably hardcoding the password in your application which isn't really safe. If you want a more secure solution to ensure that you are getting data only from users who really installed your app: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it doesn't answer your question or at least the implied one but have you considered using batched HTTP requests?

This is how Google Analytics works, it records several events (in your case location data) and then periodically it sends a batch to the server.

This will be a lot easier than messing with files.

If you want to agressively save your user's battery life you can also look at sending the request only when someone else starts up the network.  There is a great Google I/O 2012 session by Reto Meier on this.

Comment: check my edit, your answer looks very good but I need some extra info

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [andFTP](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/index.html) via an intent in sftp mode, see their FAQ on how to use that app as intent.

Answer (score 0):

One means of doing this is have a client call a web service on a remote server, sending up the data with the request (usually in JSON, but can be anything really). The web service will then take this data, process it and send a response back to the client. The response will be either success or failure or w/e you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the following code (taken mostly from [Funf](https://code.google.com/p/funf-open-sensing-framework/)) works well for this purpose:

```
public static boolean uploadFile(File file, String uploadurl) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    boolean isSuccess = true;
    try {
        // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        URL url = new URL(uploadurl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(60000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; "
            + "name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
            + file.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isSuccess = false;
    } finally {
        if (dos != null) {
            try {
                dos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do something
            }
        }
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
    // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: The code looks very well but how can I implement this with some server security? Do you know how?